# Java: Is there a version of ++ for booleans?

Tags: java

How do you use an increment operator for booleans so every time it adds ++, it changes from true to false or from false to true?

Comment: Are you referring to toggling? `boolean = !boolean`

Comment: ah yes. thank you. Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Or `boolean ^= true` to us a XOR. I find that elegant

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to toggle a boolean with `++` operator as those are generally applied on numbers. In case you want to toggle your boolean from false to true and true to false. U can use inversion operator 
e.g. `myBoolean = !myBoolean;`

Comment: How do you use this inversion when using getter and setter methods?

Comment: please share the your code where you want this. I ll be happy to help.

Comment: `set(!get())` @AllenRhodes